# Remove Layout of View on IResultFilter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, filter

How does one remove the Layout property of a view from a view on `IResultFilter.OnResultExecuting`?

EDIT:

I'm trying to remove the layout if the request is from AJAX.
The following isn't working for me:

```
public class RemoveLayoutIfRequestIsFromAjaxResultFilterAttribute : ResultFilterAttribute
    {
        

        public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
        {
            if (!(context.Result is ViewResult viewResult))
                return;

            if (context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest")
            {
                viewResult.ViewData["Layout"] = "";
            }
            else
            {
                viewResult.ViewData["Layout"] = "_Layout";
            }
        }
    }
```

I also tried the `OnResultExecuting` method with no success.

Comment: Care to elaborate? What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You should use `OnResultExecuting`. And make sure that no layout is specified in the requested view.

Comment: I can't get it to work, even after removing the layout from _views tart.

Comment: Do you delete the layout in the specified view?

Answer (score 1):

Layout is set through `ViewData`, you can change the layout of the current view through
the `ViewData["Layout"]` of `ViewResult`.

Remove the layout by setting its value to empty.

```
public class ViewLayoutAttribute : ResultFilterAttribute
{
    public ViewLayoutAttribute()
    {

    }

    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        var viewResult = context.Result as ViewResult;
        if (viewResult != null)
        {
            viewResult.ViewData["Layout"] = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
    [ViewLayout]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

**Note**: If the layout has been set in the current view, such as:

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout2";
}
```

The view will give priority to the layout(_Layout2) set by the current view.